# How can I install Windows 10 (including System Reserve) to Disk 1 instead of Disk 0?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation

I'm trying to install Windows 10 to Disk 1, which is sort of working.  I get C: and the main file system on Disk 1.  However, a "System Reserve" partition is created on Disk 0.  Also, it seems that the MBR is installed on Disk 0 as well, as I have to tell the bios to boot off of Disk 0 instead of Disk1.

How do I install Windows 10 entirely on Disk 1?  I want Windows to leave Disk 0 alone entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply disconnecting all other disk when installing Windows. Some computers also allow to disable certain SATA ports, meaning you don't need to open your computer,

Comment: It's a laptop, and disconnecting the disk is far from simple.

Comment: Also the disk it's installing the other partition to is not only not first in the boot order, it's not even in the boot list.

Comment: Does your laptop maybe have an option to disable certain SATA ports or disks? As far as I can see Windows determines the drive on which installs its boot manager onto depending on the sata ports the disk are connected to. Meaning if the HDD is connected to SATA 1 and the SSD to SATA 2 Windows will always install the boot manager onto the HDD.

Comment: Nope. No ability to disable.